# jQuery Bootstrap multi-level dropdown with mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I got this code from another [site](https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h) and I was trying to modify it but having difficulty.

When my page loads all items (a.test) have not been dropped down. If I mouseover the first a.test the jQuery works good the dropdown happens. When I mouseover on a second a.test then I want the prior a.test to no longer be toggled (dropdown). Instead I must mouse over again for the dropdown to leave.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("mouseover", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   
<div class="container">
  <h2>Multi-Level Dropdowns</h2>                                      
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">1st HTML</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd HTML</a></li>
        </ul></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">1st CSS</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd CSS</a></li>
        </ul></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
        </ul></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

If this question is not clear please provide a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu').on("mouseenter", function(e){
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('.dropdown-submenu').on("mouseleave", function(e){
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
display:none;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   
<div class="container">
  <h2>Multi-Level Dropdowns</h2>                                      
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">1st HTML</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd HTML</a></li>
        </ul></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">1st CSS</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd CSS</a></li>
        </ul></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
        </ul></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This almost is the solution.  The problem I see when I try to click on the "1st HTML". It is considered to be a mouse leave on the prior a.test.

Comment: In that case you can target parent div for js events. Check updated code